# How to recombine builds in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, parallel-processing, testing

We have a lot of tests. I can break these up so that they run on seperate agents after an initial compile build happens, but is there a way I can recombine these results? Having 8 build configurations that all need to be green makes it hard to see if you've got one ubergreen build.

Is there a way in TeamCity to recombine / join builds once we've split them out? TW-9990 might help - allowing ANDs in the dependencies.

Comment: hi, did you ever figure out the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found the answer which certainly works from TeamCity 5:

1. One compile build,
2. N test only builds that take compile.zip!** and copy to where the compile output would normally be. (via a template)
3. Consolidated finish:

   - Finish Build Trigger:     Wait for a successful build in: ...
   - Snapshot Dependencies:        Do not run new build if there is a suitable one
     Only use successful builds from suitable ones

This all seems to work nicely and the whole shbang is easily copied for branches etc. Am very happy - this has worked well for us for many months now.

Answer (score 0):

No idea how to do that natively. Here's my first thoughts on how I would try and tackle such a thing though:

- Saving test results to files
- Publishing the test result files as build artifacts
- Creating a 'Merge build'
- Adding artifact dependency onto the individual test projects
- Writing a custom 'build' script using something like (N)Ant. This would parse the individual test results and publish the results as per the [TC KB](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingTests)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside the box you could have an overall build which doesn't really do anything (or use one of your test build configs as your 'master'), with snapshot dependencies on each of your split test builds. That way if any of them fail, the 'master' will fail because one the dependent build failed.

TW-9990 looks to be concerned with build triggering rather than dependencies.